# GSON getAsString() method does not strip double quotes from JSON element?

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am  parsing this JSON using GSON, but when I try to get the deserialized string, I still end up with quotes around the element. So, for example, for the code below:

```
val ret = gson.toJson(tempObject.getAsJsonObject("medias")
        .getAsJsonObject("media").getAsJsonObject("media_sources")
        .getAsJsonArray("media_source").get(0).asJsonObject.get("source").asString)
Log.d(JOURNAL_FETCHR_TAG, "Value of ret is: $ret")
```

The value of ret is:

```
D/JournalFetchr: Value of ret is: "http://telechargement.rfi.fr/rfi/francais/audio/jff/201808/journal_francais_facile_20h00_-_20h10_tu_20180820.mp3"
```

I can just get the substring to solve my problem, but I am curious as to why asString is not giving me the string without the quotes around it? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the extra quotation marks are not part of your JSON?

Comment: Maybe, but I get the same exact Log output when I remove`asString`

`D/JournalFetchr: Value of ret is: "http://telechargement.rfi.fr/rfi/francais/audio/jff/201808/journal_francais_facile_20h00_-_20h10_tu_20180820.mp3"`

Comment: If you print the whole JSON you should easily detect whether quotes are part of your JSON or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do now is encode the string again:

```
val tempObject = JsonObject().apply {
    addProperty("a", "b")
}
val r0 = tempObject.get("a").asString                  // b
val r1 = Gson().toJson(tempObject.get("a"))            // "b"
val r2 = Gson().toJson(tempObject.get("a").asString)   // "b"
val r3 = Gson().toJson(tempObject.get("a").toString()) // "\"b\""
```

`asString` returns the string value just fine. Calling on it `toJson()` adds the quotes.